# Which memory layout should I prefer in case of a 2d matrix?

Tags: performance, optimization, caching, memory-management, computer-science

I have to declare a 2d matrix of size 100 * 100000 for caching dp solutions.
Should I use dp[100][100000] or dp[100000][100] ?

I have heard that it is preferred to keep low dimension size as the the first size because of some caching optimization. I would like to know the reason behind it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This depends on how you access the matrix, on row vs column-major and possibly other language considerations. The matrix is continuous in memory and an AxB matrix occupy the same space as a BxA matrix (unless your language requires padding between cols/rows for some reason). Matrices that big won't fit in the cache either if they were byte matrices. So it's all about how you access the elements.

Comment: The thing about keeping the low size as the first dimension (the outer dimension .. because array types are "backwards"), do you have any context for that? It makes sense if it was said about languages like Java in which arrays are reference types, but if it was said about C-like languages then it makes no sense (you can switch your loops around to make either option effectively equivalent)